# how to get packages from ubuntu ultimate edition ISO?

Tags: wine, package-management

I have an  Ubuntu Ultimate Edition 3.0 ISO,How to Extract Packages from that ISO?
It contains no /Pool Directory
A Casper Folder Containing a Squashfs File :(
I need Wine& Java Packages from it :(

Comment: does it have to be from the ISO? why not download the packages from the online repository? And please ask your questions about this OS here: http://forumubuntusoftware.info/

Comment: This isn't the correct Stack Exchange site to ask questions about non-official Ubuntu distributions (see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq)). However, it would be on-topic at [the Unix and Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run it on live mode and check /var/cache/apt directory.